# How to make a prototype function "safe" to render from an ember.js template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple patch on the native javascript date object to get me a formatted time using moment.js

```
(function() { 

  Date.prototype.utc = function() {
    return moment(this).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a");
  }

})();
```

The problem is that when I invoke this from an ember.js template using a real date object like so

```
{{input id="foo" name="foo" value=start.utc}}
```

I get the "raw" output in my template instead of the new string I was expecting

> function () {        return moment(this).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a"); 
>   }

**Update**

I realize you can create a computed property from the controller but I have this utc like formatting in a ton of templates (and non template code) so I'm looking for a solution that will let me reference the method with the least amount of boilerplate :)

Comment: Value=start.UTC() maybe

Comment: the handlebars template complains when I compile using start.utc()

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if [boundhelper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper) functions would work.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('toUTC', function(value) {
  return moment(value).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a");;
});

{{input id="foo" name="foo" value=toUTC start}}
```

Comment: you couldn't use this in the input helper, but you could use this as a view helper, then create an inputUTC helper which generates an input field with the utc.  Additionally this may be convenient since the input field is going to return it as a string and maybe you'll want to be saving it back as a Date

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a computed property in the model or controller that calls `.utc()` on the start date.  The only kind of finnicky thing about this is that since you're binding the computed property to an input field I'm assuming you'll also need to convert from the provided utc format back to a regular date type. I'd do it something like this:

```
(function() { 

  var dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a";

  Date.prototype.utc = function() {
    return moment(this).format(dateFormat);
  }

  String.prototype.utcToDate = function() {
    return moment(this, dateFormat).toDate();
  }

})();


{{input id="foo" name="foo" value=utcStart}}
```

Then the computed property, wherever you choose to place it, would be like:

```
utcStart: function(key, value) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    this.set('start', value.utcToDate());
  }
  return this.get('start').utc();
}.property('start')
```

#### Update:

If you wanted the computed property logic to be reusable, then you could turn it into a computed property macro, like [this blog post](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2013/04/27/macro/) talks about. In this case, you could do something like:

```
App.computed.utcDate = function(dateFieldName) {
  return Ember.computed(dateFieldName, function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
      this.set(dateFieldName, value.utcToDate());
    }
    return this.get(dateFieldName).utc();
  });
};
```

Then, in your controller/model, you can use it like:

```
utcStart: App.computed.utcDate('start')
```

Comment: thanks - I update the question above to mention that I have this all over my code and I'm really looking for a way to reduce the duplication (as I would need to add this to each controller that has a template doing this).

Comment: Ah, got it. OK, I updated my answer with a suggestion for how to reuse the code in the computed property.